# How to get rid of flickers in python shell?

Tags: python, comint

In a fresh emacs session, each time I hit enter in `inferior-python-mode`, the window flickers.

[image]

This does not happen in `shell-mode`. One can see the cursor goes to the middle of current window when flickers happen.

How can I get rid of these flickers? Thanks.

Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1561.4) of 2018-05-25`

Comment: How did you install Emacs? What config are you using?

Comment: See also [Bug#31115](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31115).

Answer (score 1):

See the variable `comint-scroll-show-maximum-output`, which may be somewhat at fault here for the behavior the O.P. experiences -- the default value is `t`:

```
Documentation:

Controls how to scroll due to interpreter output.
This variable applies when point is at the end of the buffer
(either because it was originally there, or because
‘comint-move-point-for-output’ said to move it there)
and output from the subprocess is inserted.

Non-nil means scroll so that the window is full of text
and point is on the last line.  A value of nil
means don’t do anything special--scroll normally.

See also the variable ‘comint-move-point-for-output’ and the function
‘comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom’.

This variable is buffer-local in all Comint buffers.
```

The *flickering* appears to be adjustment / scrolling based upon the default behavior of `scroll-margin` (and some additional re-adjusting by `comint`, *possibly* `comint-scroll-whow-maximum-output`); however, I have not done any real digging into `comint` and how it may recenter or adjust window-point after output is generated.  I personally like `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)`, which seems to fix the issue the O.P. has observed.  Feel free to play with `scroll-margin` and related settings, but they are not necessary if using the aforementioned one-liner.  [There is no need to set `scroll-conservatively` to a number beyond 101 as anything over 100 will have the same effect.]

It is possible to set `scroll-conservatively` locally with things like `setq-local` if the O.P. wishes for this to be buffer-local as to only this `*Python*` buffer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [bug reported](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31115):

> Seems like (setq scroll-conservatively 1) works better to
>   preserve the original behaviour

Worked for me. Having `scroll-conservatively` set to 1 make flickering less annoying.